# how to multi-class (One Vs. All) classification with matlab?

Tags: matlab, svm

I have 100Speakers and i want to solve my classification problem with matlab(2014). for OVA classification i use fitcsvm (matlab func. ) for each pair of speakers. The result is 100*99/2 (n (n-1)/2) classifier.
if test voice is voice of speaker1 i choose max score between these classifier:

```
speaker1-speaker2, speaker1-speaker3, ... speaker1-speaker100
```

is this true??
but the runtime is too long. Because of this for speaker1 i set it's label to +1 and all other to -1. so the result is 100 classifier. Is this wrong??

Comment: I believe that you should have 100classifiers each evaluating SpeakerX vs notSpeakerX. In the end you should run a test signal for each classifier and choose the SpeakerX that has the largest certainty in their individual SpeakerX vs notSpeakerX.

Comment: that's true, thanks. but i don't know why all of my test-Vector get the same score!!!

Comment: I am sorry I have no experience with `fitcsvm` I would suggest that you double check the dimension on the input, maybe there is a difference between rows vs columns.